# Использование регулярного выражения в xpath библиотеки lxml

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

Мне необходимо вытащить некий элемент, среди множества других элементов xml документа, - элемент определяется значением атрибута.

Значение атрибута состоит из 2х частей разделенных `#`:

- первая часть не имеет значения( может быть произвольной, для нее
  нужна регулярка)
- а вторая мне известна

**Вопрос**: можно ли использовать регулярное выражение в xpath запросе?
или есть другие пути решения?

Например, необходимо найти элемент, вторая часть которого равна:

`mem-int_ItogoNPMember`

вот так выглядит сам элемент:

```
<link:loc xlink:type="locator" xlink:href="../../../../../../udr/dom/mem-int.xsd#mem-int_ItogoNPMember" xlink:label="ItogoNPMember" xlink:title="ItogoNPMember"/>
```

Comment: прикрепите пример

Comment: @DmitryErohin , вот так подойдет, или добавить чего-нибудь?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

s = '''
    <link:loc xlink:type="locator" xlink:href="../../../../../../udr/dom/mem-int.xsd#mem-int_ItogoNPMember" xlink:label="ItogoNPMember" xlink:title="ItogoNPMember"/>
    '''

soup = bs(s, 'xml')

print(soup.findAll(href=re.compile('#mem-int_ItogoNPMember$')))
```

Comment: а это разве не регулярное выражение?